# Paginação com Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, paginação

Tenho uma dúvida, preciso fazer uma paginação quando retornar todos os registros de uma tabela, não tenho muita experiência com Spring e gostaria de saber como se faz, preciso sobrescrever findAll()? Ou no próprio metodo do controller já é possível fazer? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você está usando Spring Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Spring Data pode criar uma `interface` que estende a `interface` [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) que contém métodos adicionais para páginação.

O método [findAll](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) recebe um objeto do tipo [Pageable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html), que contém os critérios para paginação, tais como quantidade de itens, página atual, qual campo que você quer ordenar e se a ordenação é ascendente ou descendente.

Veja um exemplo:

Interface:
[image: interface]
O parâmetro Long é o tipo do Id do Usuário

Controller:
[image: controller]

O `tamanho` é quantidade de itens que deve ter na página.
O método [findAll](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) retorna um objeto do tipo [Page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) que contém as informações da pagina atual: Conteúdo, Quantidade, Total de Elementos, Quantidade de Páginas. Você pode conferir na [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) o que é retornado pelo método

Comment: Obrigado, vai ajudar muito.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que você disse me parece que você usa o Spring Data, sendo assim o próprio Spring disponibiliza outra interface que você pode estender quando estiver declarando seu repositório, sendo essa a PagingAndSortingRepository, com isso seu findAll recebe um objeto do tipo Pageable e o retorno do método findAll automaticamente vem paginado, vou te passar alguns links de referencia, qualquer coisa estou aqui e pode perguntar.

Doc interface. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html

Doc como usar. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69094)

Comment: Olá Tiago, estou começando agora no stackoverflow, mas vou fazer isso daqui para frente, muito obrigado!

Comment: Oi Leonardo, bem-vindo ao site. Você também pode [edit] suas postagens a qualquer momento e melhorá-las!